# Why does not the for loop write in the second object?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that creates a lot of .txt files in the user's desktop, and writing inside of each one something, but it just writes on the first file, it looks like that the second for loop does not work anymore.

Here is my code:

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
        String path = userHome + "/Desktop/test.txt";

        try {

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(userHome + "/Desktop/test" + j + ".txt"));
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    br.write(i);
                    br.newLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors or exception printed by `e.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: Nope, it just executes without any exception.

Comment: Firstly, put `br.close() ;` at the end of the for-loop

Comment: Which for loop?

Comment: after the internal closing-brace of the for-i loop and before the external closing-brace of the for-j loop

Comment: I put in the end of the second for loop, but out of it, and inside of the files is written "਀ਁਂਃ਄ਅਆਇਈਉ"

Comment: That's a good beginning

Comment: And what if you do `br.write(String.valueOf(i));` instead of `br.write(i);` ?

Comment: Thanks, you and horse helped me a lot

Comment: Alright; I put an answer you check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bw.write(i);` this does not print the numeric value as expected

> c - int specifying a character to be written

[Ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(int))

So, if you really need the numeric value `0` to `9` to be printed

```java
bw.write(i + 48);
```

Also, please close the stream with `bw.close()`

#### A general note in using readers/writers

Always use writers/readers with an encoding and do not assume UTF-8. It is always better to explicitly state the encoding.

Assuming you are using java 11

```java
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
        final String path = userHome + "/Desktop/";

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            final String file = path + "/test" + j + ".txt";
            try (final FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    bw.write(i + 48); // bw.write(String.valueOf(i));
                    bw.newLine();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While we are at correcting things, how about the addition of `bw` instead of `br` for a `BufferedWriter`. I'd love to know why `br` would make sense in case I'm wrong.

Comment: @Harsh, thank you for the feedback and i have updated the answer (initially used the exact variables used by OP).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your code.

```
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(userHome + "/Desktop/test" + j + ".txt"));
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    br.write(String.valueOf(i)); // instead of br.write(i);
                    br.newLine();
                }
                br.close(); // close your writer
            }
```